# Installing Google API to AWS Cloud9: "No module named 'google.api_core'"

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-api, aws-cloud9

I am trying to install the Google API Python client to AWS Cloud9 so that I can use them in a Lambda function.

I was able to install the API's using `pip install` well enough but when I paste the sample code from [Google's setup page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and run it, I get an error saying `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'google.api_core'`

I have installed the client to the working directory as per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6dmyzQb6S8) and tried upgrading the google_api_core module as per [this post](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8781)

If anyone's able to provide any help or point me in the right direction, that would be a massive help.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this? I'm facing the same error.

Comment: @MatthewSoh no, unfortunately. The workaround I used was to use the Google API in a Lambda that uses Node.js, and have the Python lambda call it. Not ideal, but it works. Would still be pleased to hear a solution, though!

Comment: I managed to find a work around using a 3rd party library called gspread! Followed these tutorials:
1. https://medium.com/@m.ivhani/setting-up-a-project-service-accounts-and-oauth-credentials-897b35be4175
2. https://medium.com/@m.ivhani/integrate-google-sheets-with-aws-lamda-python-to-send-a-recurring-email-379c8d3c5038

and adapted my code accordingly :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by manually uploading all of the google modules.  In the Cloud9 console go to `file->Upload Local Files` and find the modules you need. It's a bit tedious finding all of the correct files, but it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).